# Facebook like change of images on mouse over in asp.net using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am having an asp.net listview control to bind my image gallery. Under each listview item, i have multiple images relatively. what i want is to build a facebook like feature where on mouse over, quick views of images under the album display. please help me ..
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its as simple as activating [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin on `mouseover` and deactivating it on `mouseout`.